# Monitor default browser in android

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, monitoring

I want to know how to monitor default browser in android with knowledge of user.
I want to user do some task in their browser like chrome and get paid by me. I tried internal webview but negative performance happened. My task should done with chrome or Firefox.
I want to monitor which url opens and what user do and if my task completed they paid.
Honestly no other destructive idea!

Comment: What you want is not generally possible, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Hi. you have to use webview

Comment: @CommonsWare Is any way that google recognise my app as chrome base browser? Not as WebView?